# Failed to connect to testing-3be52.firebaseio.com port 443: Connection refused

Tags: php, firebase, curl

I am trying to read firebase's data in PHP using cURL.

```
$curl = curl_init();
$url = "https://testing-3be52.firebaseio.com/test-Details.json";
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

$result = curl_exec ($curl);
$err_status = curl_error($curl);

curl_close ($curl);
$characters = json_decode($result,true);

//...logic goes here to display the data...
```

Above piece of code is working fine. However, it failing occasionally (or when the page is refreshed/loaded multiple times), with error "`Failed to connect to testing-3be52.firebaseio.com port 443: Connection refused`".
 This error automatically gets fixed after few minutes.

I googled a lot but couldn't find any solution. Your help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the server intermittantly just doesn't want to talk to you.  If so, there's probably not too much you can do from your PHP client.

SUGGESTION:

Increase your connect timeout >> 5

Comment: changed CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT to 15 but still not working.

Comment: Unfortunately, when you're working with networked applications: a) a server is never guaranteed to be 100% available all of the time, and b) a server is never guaranteed to be infinitely responsive, replying immediately. Sometimes  you need to "wait longer", you sometimes need to "retry".  It sounds like that's probably the case here :(